# problems with registry file in filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am using filebeat to send data to elasticsearch,

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
   paths:
     - /var/log/nginx/kibana_access.log

   document_type: nginx

- input_type: log
   paths:
     - /var/log/redis/redis-server.log

   document_type: redis


output.elasticsearch:
# Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  index: '%{[type]}-log'
  versions.2x.enabled: false
```

The configuration is correct, and it is writing to elastic perfectly. But,The issue is that, it is sending the old lines to elastic also, whereas, it should not do so.

No new logs are being written, but in kibana I can see the log countto be the same as previous, when filebeata again sends the data.

I tried checking the registry file, `/var/lib/filebeat/registry`, and it had information of the files which I had used earlier but was not using now.

```
{"source":"/var/log/filebeat/filebeat","offset":2514,"FileStateOS":{"inode":4591858,"device":2058},"timestamp":"2017-04-21T17:33:11.913352399+05:30","ttl":-2},{"source":"/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-2017-04-21_120121.log","offset":4485506,"FileStateOS":{"inode":3932558,"device":2058},"timestamp":"2017-04-21T18:11:56.65579033+05:30","ttl":-2}
```

this is the registry file.

I have set a cron job which restarts filebeat every minute, and sends data to elastic. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and installed filebeat as deb package.

This is the registry file path in `filebeat.full.yml` --> `${path.data}/registry`.

Please explain this behaviour, and also the solution to this.

Comment: have you found any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

i just deleted this folder

rm -rf /var/lib/filebeat/

it was solved.